# How to use HookWidget instead of StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I am try refactor [this code](https://pub.dev/packages/confetti/example) to use HookWidget:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ConfettiController _controllerCenter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controllerCenter =
        ConfettiController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 10));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllerCenter.dispose();
    super.dispose();
```

How I can do? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom hook for `ConfettiController` then extend `HookWidget` in `MyApp`.

Sample:

***confetti_hook.dart***

```
import 'package:confetti/confetti.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

ConfettiController useConfettiController({required Duration duration}) {
  return use(_ConfettiControllerHook(duration: duration));
}

class _ConfettiControllerHook extends Hook<ConfettiController> {
  const _ConfettiControllerHook({
    required this.duration,
    List<Object?>? keys,
  }) : super(keys: keys);

  final Duration duration;

  @override
  _ConfettiControllerHookState createState() => _ConfettiControllerHookState();
}

class _ConfettiControllerHookState
    extends HookState<ConfettiController, _ConfettiControllerHook> {
  late final ConfettiController _controller =
      ConfettiController(duration: hook.duration);

  @override
  void didUpdateHook(_ConfettiControllerHook oldHook) {
    super.didUpdateHook(oldHook);

    if (hook.duration != oldHook.duration) {
      _controller.duration = hook.duration;
    }
  }

  @override
  ConfettiController build(_) => _controller;

  @override
  void dispose() => _controller.dispose();
}
```

***main.dart***

```
class MyApp extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ConfettiController controllerCenter =
        useConfettiController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 10));
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```